# php send emails to gmail without server-side modifications

Tags: php, gmail

I am trying to create a form to send me a Gmail, with a users message, name, and subject. I can't find a way to do this without changing the server. I need to because I don't have access to the server. is there any way to do this

Comment: the `mail()` function?

Comment: i cant find a way for the mail() function to send to gmail